# Batch script output file with a specific extension

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

This is probably an easy question for you.

I try to alter this script so the output file extension will be .mkv but I don't know what to change.

After many tests maybe you will know the answer.

```
@echo off
cls
set rootfolder="D:\My Videos\test"
echo Enumerating all MKVs under %rootfolder% and its subfolders.
echo.
for /r %rootfolder% %%a in (*.mkv, *.avi, *.mp4) do (
    for /f %%b in ('mkvmerge -I "%%a" ^| find /c /i "language:heb"') do (
        if [%%b]==[1] (
            echo "%%a" has Hebrew subtitles
            pause
        ) else (
            echo.
            echo "%%a" doesn't have Hebrew subtitles
            mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (heb Subs)%%~x" -S "%%a" --language 0:heb "%%~dpna.srt"
            if errorlevel 1 (
                echo Warnings/errors generated during remuxing, original file not deleted
            ) else (
                del /f "%%a"
                del /f "%%~dpna.srt"
                echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna (heb Subs)%%~xa", original file deleted
            )
            pause
            echo.
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (heb Subs)%%~x" -S "%%a" --language 0:heb "%%~dpna.srt"
```

should likely be

```
mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (heb Subs)%%~xa" -S "%%a" --language 0:heb "%%~dpna.srt"
```

which would add the original extension of the original file `%%a`. With `%%~x` it will add *nothing* since `%%x` is undefined and `~` remoes quotes from that value.

**but** sunce you want output as `.mkv` then

```
        mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (heb Subs).mkv" -S "%%a" --language 0:heb "%%~dpna.srt"
```

You'd probably also need to change 
    echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna (heb Subs)%%~xa", original file deleted

to

```
echo Successfully remuxed to "%%~dpna (heb Subs).mkv", original file deleted
```

If you want a sensible report line.

Would have been easier if you'd told us what the current output was, both as an example filename and as an error report.

Comment: thank you it works great.
do you know how do i had a single log file when it finish to a specific folder "D:\My Videos"

Answer (score 0):

In the line with `mkvmerge`, change `%%~x` to `.mkv`

`mkvmerge -q -o "%%~dpna (heb Subs).mkv" -S "%%a" --language 0:heb "%%~dpna.srt"`

Right now, it's pulling the original extension from the source file.